# Generalization of a Sphere but with dimension $n-2$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, spheres

An n-sphere (unit) is the simplest and most symmetrical manifold described by a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^1$ that is
$$
\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, f(x) = 0\} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, x^\top x - 1 = 0 
$$
where $f(x)=x^\top x - 1$.

What is the equivalent (simplest, most symmetric) manifold resulting from a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Aah I have an intuition for $n=3$. In that case I could have $f(x, y, z) = (x^2 + y^2 - 1, y^2 + z^2 -1)$ which are two one dimensional circles. One on the xy space, one on the yz space

Comment: What do you mean by level set?

Comment: Maybe in general I could define the vector $1_0 = (1, 1, \ldots, 1, 0)$ which contains $n-1$ 1s and the last entry is a zero., and equivalently $0_1$ which is all zeros except last entry which is 1. Then for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ I could write $f(x) = ((x\odot 1_0)^\top (x\odot 1_0) - 1, (x\odot 0_1)^\top (x\odot 0_1)-1)$

Comment: Your comment doesn't explain what you mean by level set.

Comment: @Euler_Salter that choice of $f$ isn't really symmetric, though, as $y$ is treated differently from $x$ and $z$.

Comment: Usually the level set $f^{-1}(0)$ in your example is called an $(n - 1)$-sphere, not an $n$-sphere.

Comment: These are not circles. You’re intersecting two cylinders. The curve you get is not everywhere smooth.

Comment: This question is too umbiguous since it is unclear what you mean by simplest and most symmetric. For instance, do the empty set and the singleton qualify? What about the whole Euclidean space?

Answer (score 9):

If $n, n - p \geq 1$, for the map $$\Phi: \Bbb R^{n + 2} \cong \Bbb R^{p + 1} \times \Bbb R^{n - p + 1} \to \Bbb R^2$$ defined by
$$\Phi({\bf x}, {\bf y}) = ({\bf x}^\top {\bf x}, {\bf y}^\top {\bf y}) ,$$ the level set $L := \Phi^{-1}(1, 1)$ is the product $$S^p \times S^{n - p}$$ of spheres, whose isometry group has dimension
$$\frac{1}{2} [n^2 - (2 p - 1) n + p^2)].$$
In the case $p = 1$, this formula specializes to $$\dim \operatorname{Iso}(S^1 \times S^{n - 1}) = {{n - 1} \choose 2} + 1,$$
but this dimension is maximal in the following sense.

First, we may as well assume that our defining function $\Phi: \Bbb R^{n + 2} \to \Bbb R^2$ has (constant) rank $2$ on level set $M$ of interest, so that $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $n$. It's (well) known that the maximal isometry group of an $n$-manifold is ${n \choose 2} = \frac{1}{2} n (n - 1)$, and that equality holds iff $L$ is isometric to a quotient of a space form (i.e., a sphere, Euclidean space, or a hyperbolic space). Wang showed that for $n \neq 4$ the largest dimension of the isometry group of an $n$-manifold that is *not* a quotient of a space form (i.e., isomorphic to a sphere, a Euclidean plane, or hyperbolic space) is exactly $${{n - 1} \choose 2} + 1 .$$

The case $\dim n = 4$ is an exception, as we have $\dim \operatorname{Iso}(\Bbb C \Bbb P^2) = \dim \operatorname{PSU}(3) = 8$. But $\Bbb C \Bbb P^2$ is not spin, so it doesn't even embed smoothly (let alone isometrically) into $\Bbb R^6$.

**Remark** In the special case $p = n - p = 1$, our construction yields the usual embedding of the flat torus $S^1 \times S^1$ into $\Bbb R^4$.

> H.C. Wang, "On Finsler spaces with completely integrable equations of Killing," *J. Lond. Math. Soc.* **22** (1947), 5–9.